# Unable to partition disk

Tags: partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to partition the disk, but without success. It shows an

> Error unmounting /dev/sda2: target is busy (udisks-error-quark,14)

I have also installed `gparted`.

How should I proceed to do the partitioning?

Comment: Partition editing requires you boot from something other than sda . Try booting from a Live USB and run gparted from there.